# Getting Sidebar Height to Equal Body Height

Tags: jquery, css

I am new to css but having a problem. I want to get the sidebar content height to match or equal the same height as the body. I am using currently but that's only good for the stating height:

```
   min-height: 240px;
```

You can find the site here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPvLb/

Scroll down the page until you see the body and to the right is the sidebar. See the difference?

Any suggestions or help on how I could do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery it's possible to do this using javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('.content', '#side').height($('.content', '#main').height());
    });
</script>
```

That will match the sidebar content height to the main content height.  Put that inside the head tag, and be sure to include the jQuery library.

A pure CSS solution is going to take much more work as already pointed out.

Here's the changes included in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPvLb/3/)

Comment: Okay I get the syntax but how would I implement that in to css sidebar sytle? new to jq!

Comment: Updated solution per your comment

Comment: Awesome much easier!! That did it my friend thank you very much!!!!! That I am sure will be VERY helpful to a lot out there looking to do this...

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe people are actually concerned with Javascript being disabled. That is such a non-existent problem. I agree with FrankG. Disabling JS should not even be an option.

Never worry about user not having JS enabled, that should just be put to rest.

Answer (score 1):

This is called by some the "Holy Grail" of CSS, and for good reason: it's inordinately unintuitive to do, due mostly to the way CSS heights work.

There's hope, though: Matthew Taylor's done an excellent writeup on the problem, though I suspect that to use his solution you'll need to edit your structure a bit.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm

Comment: Hello Sudowned but can be achieved much easier and faster with Jquery below... But this is helpful to know. Thank you very much for your help as well!!!

Comment: @FrankG., jQuery (or indeed, JavaScript) is a bad solution. Using JS for layout code means that your site will look broken on browsers that have JS disabled, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Yea but the same can go with css. Than can change font sizes, colors etc... unfortunately browsers give user to much control. And cookies and JS should not be allowed to be disabled anymore. Technology is relying on them more and more. At least that's my opinion!! Thanks!

Comment: The percentage of browsers that don't support CSS is virtually non-existent, and users who have disabled it are explicitly choosing to browse broken sites. In contrast, somewhere between 1-4% of viewers in the US browse with JavaScript disabled, and a layout - not functionality, but the layout itself - which breaks with scripting off is fundamentally different. Your page may validate, but **going with JavaScript to solve this problem is wrong.**

Comment: "going with JavaScript to solve this problem is wrong". Javascript is usefull for style related tasks, users with js disabled will only see a shorter sidebar which is no problem at all. The only thing where javascript is wrong is for content related tasks, like loading content via ajax etc.

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions out there just don't work or are too complicated. (Frustrating, considering this is so easy with tables.)

It's usually the homepage that is broken because fonts and images haven't had a chance to load before sizing the sidebar, especially on a slow connection.

First, explicitly define the width and height of all of your images with CSS.  If you don't specify the size of an image, the browser has no way of knowing how tall or wide (for wrapping text) the page will be.

Next, as far as web fonts, this is my solution. Simply "slide" your content into place with jQuery. This only needs to happen once on the homepage.

```
$(function() {
    $("#content").slideDown('slow').promise().always(function(){
        $("#sidebar").height($("#content").height()); // drop sidebar down
    }); // Just show homepage content
});
```

Granted, your page will be different. Here's a more complete [example](http://linkedexpertsalliance.com/linkedin-consultant.html).

Essentially, your sidebar gets resized *after* it slides into place. This keeps your sidebar from sizing itself too short before your fonts have had a chance to load.